# Need to check the files that are being uploaded from my system in the background

Tags: networking, malware

I've noticed in the System app that sometimes high upload speed, even when there's no application running.
I suspect this could be the work of some malware, and so I'd like to check which IP is being accessed by which service so that I can make sure that my system's safe.

The built in apps don't seem to give me that information by the way.

Comment: Search for "tcpdump tutorial" on the Internet...

Comment: You can also use the graphical alternative named [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).But you cannot find which program is exhausting your network bandwidth via Wireshark. For that you can use ```netstat -tnp```. That will show you all of the TCP connections in your system.Or if you want to check UDP connections also , don't use the *t* option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command-line program named **tcpdump** as @FedonKadifeli mentioned but that has a learning curve and it's very difficult to analyze the data with it on-the-fly because there are so much.

But you can use the graphical alternative (this area is of the few ones that I prefer graphical apps over CLI) named [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

But that doesn't show you which program is exhausting your bandwidth.In order to find that out , you can use [netstat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) :

```
netstat -np
```

That will not only shows you all the network connection in your system but all the associated processes are listed alongside their PIDs.

Then go to Wireshark and set a filter to monitor a specific Foreign IP address or a specific port in your system.

For instance , one of entries in the **Active Internet connections (w/o servers)** section of the output of **netstat** in my system is this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.104:51116     212.103.50.247:9002     ESTABLISHED 3029/firefox
```

You can see that a firefox process with the PID of **3029** has made a connection (**ESTABLISHED**) to the address **212.103.50.247** from the local port **51116** to the remote port **9002** and of course the protocol is **TCP**.

Now you can go to the Wireshark and start listening on your Wi-Fi interface (possibly something like `wlanX` or `wlpXYZ`) :

[image]

and then add a filter and then you're able to see the packets sent to or received from that address :

[image]

But note that you aren't able to see the files or contents that are being downloaded or uploaded here if the packets are **encrypted**.

And note that after installing Wireshark , you have to add your user to the **wireshark** group ( via `sudo addgroup your_user wireshark` ) and then log-out and log-back to be able to capture packets without root access.Also when you install it via **apt** , the **postint** scripts should ask you this :

[image]

You should select **Yes**.

If you don't do this , then you have to open Wireshark as root to able to capture packets because wireshark uses [libpcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) to capture packets and the libpcap itself makes use of the [Netlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) communication platform to be able to receive the contents of a packet from the corresponding kernel infrastructure.And the Netlink protocol requires constructing [**RAW Sockets**](https://opensourceforu.com/2015/03/a-guide-to-using-raw-sockets/) which needs root access in Unix systems.

And running a graphical program like Wireshark which has almost 1.5 million lines of code as root is dangerous so it's a good practice to run it as a regular user.

---

Hope it helps.